# Problem in creating host only adapter in windows 10 docker

Tags: docker, vmware, docker-toolbox

I am wanted to use docker toolbox but the VM is causing problems as host only network adapter is not being created.
(I am new using docker toolbox and VM, plus I got two 2 VM in VMware,does this affect?)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lU7vH.png)

I have tried rebooting after installation, running it as admin, but it still left me banging my head.

Also there is exclamation mark on host-only-network adapter in device manager and it is not visible on network connections.

Answer (score 0):

As told within the description of the docker toolbox is a not more supported legecy project.

Maybe upgrade to Docker for Windows now?

[image]